# How do I prevent my navbar and footbar from breaking when resizing the window?

Tags: html, css, window, resize

I'm currently building some test pages to practice HTML/CSS and came across this problem. When I resize the browser window, it breaks the navbar and footer. Been stuck for two days trying to solve this, so any help would be appreciated.

[My navbar should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mexFZ.png)

[But when I resize it, it becomes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqG6m.png)

And my footer

[should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw5FH.png)

[But it is like this after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daW3t.png)

```css
position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 14px;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #4a7585;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 30px;
}

nav li { 
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
background-color: #629eb3;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 5px;
width: 42%;
position: relative;
left: 28.6%;
top: 25px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

footer li {
padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

footer span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

.footer-links {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
    <nav id="nav-bar">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/AU8WZR6.png" alt="The Pen Store logo" width="180" height="60"> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link"> Pricing </a></li>      
        <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="nav-link"> How it Works </a></li>
        <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link"> Features </a></li>      
      </ul>

    </nav>

      <footer>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=# class="footer-links">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href=# class="footer-links">Terms</a></li>
      <li><a href=# class="footer-links">Work for The Pen Store</a></li>
    </ul>
      <span>The Pen Store 2022 © - All rights reserved</span>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @media. Take a look at some examples or how to use it. It will set some break points and apply another type of css. For example, when a page has a phone width, it apply some css, but if the width is bigger than a phone, apply another css. Or use Bootstrap.

Comment: Hey, using @media worked, thanks!